# Qt5: how to connect to D-Bus signals

Tags: qt, bluetooth, signals, dbus, hfp

I'm trying to connect a D-Bus signal to a Qt slot. For example, I'm interested to catch the `CallAdded` signal:

http://git.kernel.org/cgit/network/ofono/ofono.git/tree/doc/voicecallmanager-api.txt

I did the folloging:

```
QDBusConnection::systemBus().connect(OFONO_SERVICE, m_modem.path(), OFONO_VOICECALLMANAGER_INTERFACE, "CallAdded", this, SLOT(callAdded(QString,QMap<QString,QVariant>)));
```

where:

```
OFONO_SERVICE = "org.ofono"
m_modem.path() = /hfp/org/bluez/hci0/dev_xx_xx_x_xx_xx_xx
OFONO_VOICECALLMANAGER_INTERFACE = "org.ofono.VoiceCallManager"
```

but nothing happens when I make or receive a call. Of course I'm connected and I've enabled and set online the modem.

Perhaps my "translated" signature is wrong?

Comment: The arguments are `o, a{sv}`, so have you tried `QDBusObjectPath` for `o`?